# hadoop -cp limit number of files

Tags: hadoop, hdfs, cp

Is there a way to limit the number of files I can `cp` in hadoop?

For instance, in my target directory `/data/d_20151111-2350/` contains 8 files. These files have random numbers in them so I can't use regex to select a couple. I was wondering if there was something along the lines of

`hadoop fs -cp /data/d_20151111-2350/* /dest/location/ LIMIT 2`

Where `LIMIT 2` means 2 files.

Answer (score 1):

No there is no such a parameter

See also:

```
https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r2.4.1/hadoop-project-dist/hadoop-common/FileSystemShell.html#cp
```

The best way to solve this is writing a python or shell script-

Comment: I think I might just write a python script and use webhdfs API. Thanks for the help!